# Paginator in python django crashes on dict

Tags: python, django

I have 2 types of gathered data from database:

One is `[<NaseljenoMesto: NaseljenoMesto object>, <NaseljenoMesto: NaseljenoMesto object>]`

And another is: `[{'naseljenomesto_drzava__naziv': u'Srbija', 'sifraMesta': u'ZR', 'nazivMesta': u'Zrenjanin', 'id': 3}, {'naseljenomesto
_drzava__naziv': u'Srbija', 'sifraMesta': u'BG', 'nazivMesta': u'Beograd', 'id': 1}]`

First is QuerySet type and another is ValuesQuerySet.

Now i have Paginator: `paginator = Paginator(filteredData, rowsPerPage)`

In first case paginator works but in second crashes. How to correct this?

### EDIT

```
Internal Server Error: /TestProjekat/main/getFormData/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\DA_LI_RADI\Test projekat\st_forms\views.py", line 238, in getFormData
    serializedData = serializers.serialize("json", data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\__init__.py", line 99, in serialize
    s.serialize(queryset, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 46, in serialize
    concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

### EDIT 2

```
paginator = Paginator(filteredData, rowsPerPage)

try:
    data = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    data = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    data = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

serializedData = serializers.serialize("json", data)
```

### NEW ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Milan\Desktop\DA_LI_RADI\Test projekat\st_forms\views.py", line 238, in getFormData
    serializedData = json.dumps({'data': data})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Page 1 of 1> is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Please post the traceback/error you get from the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the pagination, but the way you serialize your data: `serializers.serialize` is built to serialize Django model instances (from a list or a `QuerySet`), nothing else. You can use the `json` module from the python stdlib to serialize 'raw' dictionaries, try for example:

```
import json
print json.dumps({'your': 'dict'})
```

You might need to convert the `ValuesQuerySet` to a vanilla list-of-dicts to convince the `json` module to work, though:

```
# [...]
data = paginator.page(1)
print json.dumps(list(data))
```

Comment: How to convert to vanilla list-of-dicts?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly: you can pass the `Page` object, that is stored in the data variable in your example, into the `list` constructor (because `Page` is [iterable](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)).

Comment: Ok now works :). But i have another problem now. How to get this data on page. I send response like this: `return HttpResponse({'rows':list(data)})` how to process this list on html page? After all of this i have(jQuery) `deserializedData=$.parseJSON(response)` but now this not working...

Comment: Here (`return HttpResponse({'rows':list(data)})`) you are trying to directly return a dict as a response. This won't work. You need to return the string output of `json.dumps` or, for your other kind of data, the `serializers.serialize` output. Also, you should set a content type on your response, for example: `HttpResponse(..., content_type="application/json")`